# How to authenticate a user in blackberry against an online database?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am fairly new to Blackberry development and need help in terms of having a simple application. User enters a login/password which is authenticated on a MYSQL database on website. Once authenticated, he/she is shown a listbox/select boxthat is pre populated with some values. Once the user selects a value and hits submit, an email is generated and sent to a dummy email address.

Can someone guide me to either a good tutorial and/or some instructions that can help me set up something like that. Again I am a seasoned developer that is making a transition to Blackberry development. All replies would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some good Blackberry dev tools on the RIM [website](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/), you can get a simulator for each type of handset you need to support.  When it comes to authentication, as you already suggested, entering credentials is the easiest thing to support, but a bit of a pain for users, you can also look at using your Blackberry gateway as a kind of signing authority and enabling pin/email http headers (see [here](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB03275))

In terms of development, just remember you want a style sheet as basic as possible, and a webpage which is only 320px wide, otherwise its just another browser...